# How to take more than one dynamic integer python inputs?

Tags: python-3.x, input

Suppose I need to input three **integers** *a,b,c* dynamically.

It's supposed to run using: **test.py int1 int2 int3**

I tried,

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
c = int(input())
```

But, it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Use `sys` module with `arv` attribute to access *the list of command line arguments passed to a Python script*:

```
import sys

a, b, c = sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3]
```

Usage:

```
python test.py 1 2 3
```

Comment: I got _TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting_

Comment: @AnkS, that means that you did not post the entire code. It seems that you are using formatting somewhere after obtaining values

Comment: @AnkS, you should post it in your question